# How to distort the shape of a DIV

Tags: html, css

How do I create the shapes down below. I am trying to create this kind of shape where the DIVs are distorted. The DIV on the left is distorted and the DIV on the left is distorted as well but in a reverse order. The top side of the right DIV stretches over into the left DIV and the bottom of the left DIV stretches into right DIV. How can I pull off this design?.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
     <img src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="image" />
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <h1 class="headings">THE LEADER IN INTERACTIVE VR</h1>
    <p class="text">Founded in 2011, Loop Studios has been producing world class Virtual Reality projects for some of the best companies around the globe. Our award winning creations have transformed businesses through digital experiences that bind to their brand.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: absolute and relative positioning

Comment: they do not look "distorted" to me, just one is overlapping the other

Comment: Okay I have observed that, how can I pull off the design ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to put `position: relative` to the parent and align the elements with `position: absolute`. you can push the image to the background with a negative `z-index`:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container > * {
  width: 52%;
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
}

.container img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" alt="image" />
  <div class="left">
    <h1 class="headings">THE LEADER IN INTERACTIVE VR</h1>
    <p class="text">Founded in 2011, Loop Studios has been producing world class Virtual Reality projects for some of the best companies around the globe. Our award winning creations have transformed businesses through digital experiences that bind to their brand.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```